# Kivy - pass value from one screen to another via setting a current page

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to change a screen in Kivy to exit screen, where I have a two buttons. `Yes`, `No`. If I press `Yes` I want to normally end a code. When `No` I would like to return back on the previous page, but I'm not able to pass a name of previous page to the `exit page`

My App Class's method

```py
    def change_screen(self, screen_name, type_=SlideTransition(), page_before=None):
        # Get screen_manager from main.kv file
        screen_manager = self.root.ids['screen_manager']

        # Set transition (https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html)
        if type_ == "RiseInTransition":
            screen_manager.transition = RiseInTransition()
        else:
            screen_manager.transition = SlideTransition()

        if page_before: #tried **kwargs, doesn't work, because current accept only str
            page_before = {"page_before": page_before}
            screen_manager.current = screen_name
```

.kv file

```py
            Button:
                text: "end"
                size_hint : .2, .1
                pos: ((root.width - self.width) -20, 20)
                background_color : 0.1, 0.5, 0.6, 1
                on_release:
                    app.change_screen("exit_screen", type_="RiseInTransition", page_before="something")
```

How could I pass the `page_before` variable to the

```py
class ExitScreen(Screen):
    pass
```

???

Answer (score 0):

You can call `on_press: root.manager.current = 'YourScreenName'`  directly in the kv language to make screen transitions a bit easier?

Try the example below:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

Builder.load_string("""
<MainScreen1>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        Button:
            text: 'Yes'
            on_press: root.buttonpress()
        Button:
            text: 'No'
            on_press: 
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
                root.manager.current = 'screen2'
                root.otherfunction()

<MainScreen2>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        Button:
            text: 'No'
            on_press: root.buttonpress()
        Button:
            text: 'Yes'
            on_press: 
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'up'
                root.manager.current = 'screen1'
                root.otherfunction()
                    
""")

# Declare both screens
class MainScreen1(Screen):
    def buttonpress(self):  # load in new bdf function graph
        print("You pressed a button on screen1")
    def otherfunction(self):
        print("do other function")
        
class MainScreen2(Screen):
    def buttonpress(self):  # load in new bdf function graph
        print("You pressed a button on screen2")
    def otherfunction(self):
        print("do other function")
        
# Create the screen manager
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MainScreen1(name='screen1'))
sm.add_widget(MainScreen2(name='screen2'))

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Any questions just ask.